# can i go into c# windows developer after having experience in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Webforms to Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714513/webforms-to-winforms)

guys i have this doubt, can i go into c# windows developer after having experience in asp.net? and how is the pay in C# development, and what about the scope? are companies using C# in development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can and you have already done the first half of writing code in c# before.

Answer (score 0):

The C# code is the same for WinForm and WebForm development, as is the .Net framework itself.

BUT: the way the code interacts with the page is completely different! No postback, no page lifecycle etc.

Comment: Ah, but the ASP.NET WebForms model was designed to emulate the WinForms experience as much as possible - trying to make the web "stateful", layering the events system (Page (form) load, button clicks, etc) that WinForms devs are used to, etc, etc, so some of the concepts will be similar.

Comment: @ Zhaph, it was designed to emulate WinForms, but it will thoroughly do your head in if you go into it with the expectation that you will be facing the same problems. Having said that it is going to be easier going to WinForms from WebForms than the other way round.

Comment: thankx to zhaph and mongus pong, they were really informative